# How to delete the log messages in a file based on timestamp/ messages older than 7 days should be deleted from file

Tags: linux, bash, datetime, unix, sed

How to delete the log messages in a file based on timestamp/ messages older than 7 days should be deleted from file.

Log File Messages Sample-

```
2022-12-21T09:36:48+00:00 LONSTBYRDEV02 auth_log:
```

These are lines in the file with time stamp at the start, I just want to delete all the data which are older than 7 days. In this case , considering today's date 22nd December so it should delete all lines before 15th december

Do you know any command or anything which I can include inside the script and remove the lines using loop or something.

Please suggest.

Can anyone help based on above scenario, it should delete all lines older than 15th Dec in this case.

I have written this and further nothing is working.

My COde-

```
current_DT=$(date +"%m-%d-%y-%T")
echo $current_DT

cutoff=$( date -d "7 days ago"  +"%m-%d-%y-%T")
echo $cutoff

while read -r line ; do
  timestamp=$( date -d "$( echo $line)" )
  echo $timestamp
  if [ $timestamp -gt $cutoff ] ; then
    echo "  Timestamp over cutoff old. Deleting lines."
    sed -i "/^$hostname:/d" $hosts
  fi
done
```

Output I am getting is-

```
12-22-22-08:17:22
12-15-22-08:17:22
```

Comment: Better use `logrotate` instead of reinventing badly the wheel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using GNU date and any awk:

```
awk -v date="$(date -d'-7 days' +'%F')" '$1 >= date' file
```

That's the entire script, no loop required.

If you want to update the original file then use GNU awk for `-i inplace` or use the ubiquitous `cmd file > tmp && mv tmp file` idiom with any awk.

Comment: For more precision, you should use `+%FT%T`.  (The quotes around the time format are not necessary.)

Comment: @Jack quotes in shell aren't something you add when you need to add them, they're something you always use by default and remove when you need to remove them. They're like seatbelts when driving - if you don't use them until you think you might need them then you'll probably end up regretting that approach one day. As for adding `T%T` to the format - on re-reading the question I now think you're probably right but I'll leave it for the OP to let us know.

Comment: I've had things working and had others put in those quotes and break things.  I prefer to put in what I need and nothing more.

Comment: @Jack Of course you can't just add quotes or any other characters to existing code without considering what that code does and assume it won't break that code. Everyone who ever had their code fail because of not using quotes thought they were writing the code they need. I've been writing shell scripts for 40+ years and so have come across plenty of examples of that and still see it almost daily. Your code so your call of course - all the best with your programming.

Comment: @Jack - in case it helps demonstrate the issue, I just added a comment under your answer of why you should be using quotes in your script. If you want to do any reading on the subject, there are a TON of well-written articles on quoting strings, scripts, and variables in shell, including the answers at [security-implications-of-forgetting-to-quote-a-variable-in-bash-posix-shells](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171346/security-implications-of-forgetting-to-quote-a-variable-in-bash-posix-shells)

Comment: I, too, have been writing shell scripts for 40+ years, thank you.  I use quotes when they are needed, and don't when they are not.

Comment: @Jack They are needed in the script in [your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74889229/1745001) but you aren't using them so YMMV.

Comment: No, they are not.

Comment: @Jack please just read and think about my comments as there's really nothing more to say other than providing more examples which I'm not going to bother doing. Try the examples I've provided if you you don't understand them (but don't do the first one on a computer you care about - maybe try a briefer string to see the effect without crashing your computer!). Take the advice or don't, either way all the best with your programming.

Comment: Thanks Ed, It worked on my sample File . Testing it on Original File now.

Comment: Hi @Ed , there is one more condition, which needs to be integrated here like our syslog file will be running 24*7 and generating records 24*7 , so while this script is running through crontab, the new logs will also be getting written in the main syslog file.  

So if we are using above code and replacing the lines by latest records, will those records recently added in syslog file be overwritten.

If yes, can you suggest how to handle this scenario.

Comment: @samh125679 you should ask a new question about that as [chameleon questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions) are strongly discouraged on this forum.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, for logs, you would (as @Gilles Quenot sugested in the comments) use `logrotate` for your logging. I assume that, for some reason, you need something different.

You can look at it the other way around: not delete everything older, but keep everything 7 days.

```
#!/bin/bash

logfile="$1"

for i in $(seq 0 6) ; do
    day=$(date +%Y-%m-%d -d -%{i}days)
    grep "^${day}T" "$logfile"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps another approach.  Look for newer lines, then stop.

```
# Set cutoff mark to start of file
mark=0

# Get cutoff time in seconds
cutoff=$( date -d '7 days ago' +%s )

# Loop through file
while read line
do
    # Separate date
    line_date=$( echo $line | cut -d' ' -f1 )

    # Convert to seconds
    line_sec=$( date +%s ${line_date} )

    # If newer, get out of loop
    [ ${line_sec} -gt ${cutoff} ] && break

    # Move mark to next line
    (( mark++ ))
done < my.log

# Delete older lines
sed -i "1,${count}d" my.log
```

Comment: See [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice).

Comment: As an example of why you should use quotes - if the input file contained `foo * bar` then `echo $line` would expand to `foo` followed by a list of all files in your current directory then `bar` rather than printing `foo * bar` which is obviously undesirable. If you quoted your variable as `echo "$line"` then that wouldn't happen.

Comment: In which case, it would not start with a valid date and would fail.  So, in this case, quotes are not needed.  If it starts with a valid date, the rest of the line is irrelevant.

Comment: Regarding `If it starts with a valid date, the rest of the line is irrelevant.` - no, it doesn't matter what the line starts with you're going to read and then echo that line and encounter the problem I described. Obviously `foo` wasn't meant to be literal anyway, it could be `2022-12-21T09:36:48+00:00 LONSTBYRDEV02 auth_log: executing 2 * 7 failed` which starts with a date and would cause the problem I described.

Comment: As one example of why leaving `$line` unquoted is a problem, imagine some attacker managed to get `/*/*/*/*/../../../../*/*/*/*/../../../../*/*/*/*` (example borrowwd from https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/171347/133219) into the log file you're reading (e.g. with some incoming query they deliberately initiated for this purpose) - your `echo $line` would attempt to expand that to all associated paths, sucking up all of the CPU and/or memory on your machine and so allowing that denial of service attack.

Comment: As another example, imagine you have files in your local directory with names that contain newlines and your log file contains a line like `2022-12-21T09:36:48+00:00 LONSTBYRDEV02 auth_log: executing 2 * 7 failed`. - your `echo $line` would expand that `*` to be multiple lines, split at every newline from the filenames, and so the result of the `cut` would be multiple lines of strings which would cause the subsequent call to `date` to fail.

Comment: Again, just like seatbelts, you don't use quotes by default to protect you from the things you expect, you use them by default to protect you from the things you don't expect and shell programming is complicated enough that it's extremely difficult to always think of all possible situations (including the very real, daily case of attackers trying to exploit your code) before deciding you definitely will never need quotes in any given piece of code.

Comment: I use them, or not, as needed.  That `*` does not put newlines into the output.  It's all one line, with space-separated names.  So the `cut` results in exactly what one expects -- the date.

Comment: From what I've seen and heard so far, you don't use them when you **think** you don't need them but you're not considering all rainy day cases. The `*` expands to the list of file names in the current directory. If one of those file names contains a newline then the output of `echo $line` will contain that newline and then the output of `cut` will be 2 lines. If you don't believe me do `> $'foo\nbar'; line='2022 * stuff'; echo $line` and you'll see the output is 2 lines, `2022 foo` and `bar stuff` and the output of piping that to `cut` will be `2022` and `bar`.

Comment: So at that point `line_date` will contain `2022<newline>bar` and when you use THAT variable unquoted in the call to date it'll become `date +%s -d 2022 bar` which will cause date to fail. (I just noticed you're missing the `-d` in your call to date btw).

Comment: If a file name contains a newline, someone needs to be shot.

Comment: A common sentiment but that doesn't stop such files from existing, nor remove the need for us to write software that will continue to work when they do. I gave you a couple of examples (there are more) of why you need quotes in the code you wrote, take them however you like, adapt your coding practice or not. Either way, I hope you have a great holiday season. All the best.

Comment: Been doing this 40 years, not once seen a file with an embedded newline character.  I'm sure you'll put one in yourself sometime.